# foreach $_POST [key] PHP

Tags: php, post, foreach, tcpdf

I need to **insert keys into $_POST**. Is there a way to reach this? I'm newer in PHP.

```
    $mat_list_data = '';

    foreach( $_POST['mat_tit'] as $key => $_POST['mat_tit'] ) {
      $mat_list_data .= '
        <table" cellspacing="1">
            <tr>
                <td>'.$_POST['mat_tit'].'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
```

/* from here */

```
            <td>'.$_POST['mat_up'].'</td>
            <td>'.$_POST['mat_q'].'</td>
            <td>'.$_POST['mat_ut'].'</td>
            <td>'.$_POST['mat_c'].'</td>
            <td>'.$_POST['mat_isum'].'</td>
            <td>'.$_POST['mat_vv'].'</td>
            <td>'.$_POST['mat_sv'].'</td>
            <td>'.$_POST['mat_itot'].'</td>
```

/* to here */

```
            </tr>
        </table>';
}

    $pdf->writeHTML($mat_list_data, true, true, false, true, 'L');
```

If theres an easier process, please tell me. Thanks a lot to any direction.

Comment: Um, what? Insert keys into $_POST? What's with that crazy `foreach`? What do the /*from here*/ and /*to here*/ lines indicate?

Comment: It indicates where I want to insert keys (for which vars).

Comment: As I said, I'm newer in PHP and if I said this I meant this. I'm sooo sorry, if U don't like it. Cheers for reaction

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST[]` is a superglobal array, specifically one that references HTTP data that has been posted. For this reason adding data to the array will likely make your code more confusing and error prone, as it would not be posted information.

As with all the superglobals, you should treat them as special case sources of input data; Reading the data into local variables and then using correct sanitation.

For example:

```
$data = $_POST['matt_tit'];
$results = array();
foreach($data as $name => $value) {
  $results[$name] = $this->sanitiseData($value); // Filter input
}
// Now use $results rather than $_POST
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to assign it's value to $_POST, you can use a simple array. I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but I'll give it a shot:

```
    $mat_list_data = '<table" cellspacing="1"><tr>';

    foreach( $_POST as $Values ) {
      $mat_list_data .= '<td>' . $Values . '</td>';
      }
    $mat_list_data .= '</tr></table>'
```